# Ruby On Rails Testing environment speedup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I have a basic question. 
I already have a RoR application which has hundreds of test cases defined.
Recently, I came across a term called "Spork". Now this gem is supposed to increase the speed of the execution of test cases (or loading of it)
I did search a lot on the same, but could not make head or tail of it.
Can someone help me out on this and make me understand how to use Spork?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read documentation http://rubydoc.info/gems/spork/0.9.0/frames

Comment: I did go through it, but i still am not clear how to run all the test cases using spork. I use rake to run all my test cases. spork just starts listening on a port. how can i use spork to run all my test cases. Is there any other link that can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add Spork to your gemfile

  - then bundle install

For rspek run:

- spork rspec --bootstrap

For cucumber run:

- spork cucumber --bootstrap

and for testunit,install the spork-testunit gem and run:

- spork test_unit --bootstrap

Follow the instructions.

Finally, run spork. A DRb server will be running!:

- spork

On this time if you run your tests with "rake spec" the drb server is loaded and your tests will pass in minimum half the time

For additional informations look at the [spork githup repo](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork)